# RadListView better scrollToIndex() behavior

Tags: nativescript, radlistview

RadListView.scrollToIndex() seems to display the selected item at the bottom of the current window always - regardless of whether the item is already visible or not.

Is there a function like RadListView.isVisible()?

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested the given scenario with `scrollToIndex()` and was unable to reproduce such a behavior. Selected row has been always displayed in the top of the screen. You could review my sample code.

main-page.xml

```
<Page   loaded="onPageLoaded" xmlns:lv="nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/listview" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
    <lv:RadListView id="rdid" loaded="radlistviewlaoded" items="{{ dataItems }}" >
        <lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
            <lv:ListViewLinearLayout scrollDirection="Vertical"/>
        </lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
        <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                <Label fontSize="20" text="{{ itemName }}"/>
                <Label fontSize="14" text="{{ itemDescription }}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
    </lv:RadListView>
</Page>
```

main-page.ts

```
import { EventData } from "data/observable";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { HelloWorldModel } from "./main-view-model";
import { ObservableArray } from "data/observable-array";
import { RadListView } from "nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/listview";
import {setTimeout} from "timer"

// Event handler for Page "navigatingTo" event attached in main-page.xml
export function onPageLoaded(args: EventData) {
    // Get the event sender
    var page = <Page>args.object;
    var listview:RadListView = <RadListView> page.getViewById("rdid");
    console.log("listview visibility "+listview.visibility);
    //listview.scrollToIndex(3);
    var array = new ObservableArray();
    for(var i=0;i<20;i++){
        array.push({itemName:"Name "+i, itemDescription:"desc "+i});
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        listview.scrollToIndex(3)
    }, 2000)

    page.bindingContext = {dataItems:array};
}

export function radlistviewlaoded(args:EventData){
    console.log("RadListView loaded");
}
```

About the second question you could use `loaded` event in case you want to know when the view has been loaded on the screen. In case you would like to know  if the RadListview is visible you could use [visibility](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_ui_enums_.visibility.html) property.

Comment: You have to do it with a lot more entries and scroll to somewhere in the middle or end of the list. if you change your "for" to 200 and then to a scrollToIndex to 180 or so - it should display that entry at the bottom of the view. That's not the problem. The problem is when that item is already in the view - it scrolls and moves to the bottom of the view. The second part of question has to do with if a list-item is visible - not the listview itself. I was going to do "if  not item.isVisible() then item.scrollToIndex()"